# Error al ejecutar npm install @angular/cdk --save

Tags: angular

Al ejecutar `npm install @angular/cdk --save`, me genera error.
Dejo aqui el error que se genera

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: helpdesk@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@4.4.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^4.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@12.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente tienes instalado una versión de nodeJs / npm con angular que es mucho más reciente que la configurada en ese proyecto. O simplemente hay líos al resolver la versión de cdk que vas a usar comparada con la versión de node o de npm.

Prueba `npm install @angular/cdk --save --legacy-peer-deps`.